# Replace Substring in a text file with a text file of strings using Sed

Tags: string, bash, sed, grep

I'm trying to replace substrings in a text file [corpus.txt] with some other substrings using sed. I have the list of possible substrings in a file `sub.txt` containing the following:

```
dogs chase
birds eat
chase birds
chase cat
chase birds .
```

and a `corpus.txt` containing some texts as below:

```
dogs chase cats around
dogs bark
cats meow
dogs chase birds
cats chase birds , birds eat grains
dogs chase the cats
the birds chirp
```

with the desired output

```
<bop> dogs chase <eop> cats around
dogs bark
cats meow
<bop> dogs chase <eop> birds 
cats <bop> chase birds <eop> , <bop> birds eat <eop> grains
<bop> dogs chase <eop> the cats
the birds chirp
```

Using the Command `sed -f <(sed 's/.*/s|\\b&\\b|<bop> & <eop>|g/' sub.txt) corpus.txt` it returns everything in the desired output correctly, except in the fifth line where it returns :

```
cats <bop> <bop> chase birds . <eop>eop> , <bop> birds eat <eop> grains
```

What can I do to get this to work?

Comment: you're asking for it, your first file has two `chase birds`.  Perhaps pass it from `uniq` to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: Hi karakfa, they aren't duplicates. I have `chase birds` and `chase birds .`

Comment: OK, do you agree that if `chase birds .` matches, `chase birds` matches as well.  And the first one will match any char due to `.` being a special char.  So both matches takes place.  If you want a literal match, escape `.` with \ in your sub.txt file

Comment: I don't think I would agree that if `chase birds .` matches, `chase birds` matches as well. In the worst case I expect it to match just  `chase birds` .

Comment: Second one is a subset of the first one.  It has to match by definition.  However, the problem here is if you want a literal `.` match you have to escape it.

Comment: Is there a way I can fix that in my command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to escape the `.` in the first file to make a literal match

```
$ sed -f <(sed 's/\./\\./;s/.*/s|\\b&\\b|<bop> & <eop>|g/' sub_o.txt) file

<bop> dogs chase <eop> cats around
dogs bark
cats meow
<bop> dogs chase <eop> birds
cats <bop> chase birds <eop> , <bop> birds eat <eop> grains
<bop> dogs chase <eop> the cats
the birds chirp
```

Comment: That works fine @karakfa, I added `dogs chase-@@ boy` to the corpus and changed the seed command to `sed -f <(sed 's/\./\\./;s/\-/\\-/;s/.*/s|\\b&\\b|<bop> & <eop>|g/' sub.txt) corpus.txt` by trying to escape `-` but it seems not to work.

Comment: hyphen is not special unless in square brackets. no need to escape.

Comment: Yes, but I get `<bop> dogs chase <eop>@@- boy` instead of just having `dogs chase@@- boy` as it is.

Comment: As it should.  `@` creates a word boundary (similar to white space) and it matches the rest as you specified.

Comment: Oh! I see.. Is there a way I can ensure I get `dogs chase@@- boy` from the sed command?

Comment: you have to decide what is a match, space delimited words or punctuation marks OK.

Comment: I'm interested in space delimited words that is why I used `\\b&\\b` but seems that is not enough. Therefore, sequences in `sub.txt` should match space delimited sequence (substrings) in `corpus.txt`.